# Hack to restart Rstudio session within a loop ... from Rstudio

Tags: r, memory-management, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, rstudio

I am currently running some simulations which fill large amounts of memory. Unfortunately, `gc()` and `rm(list=ls())` have not successfully released this memory on my windows machine. Consequently, I have had to find a way to restart the rsession, releasing memory to windows. I spent a few hours trawling forums in vain, so here is my working solution for any other users who encounter the same problem.

By saving the iteration as an external file, and writing an rscript which calls itself, the session can be restarted within a for loop from within rstudio. This example requires the following steps.

Save an the iteration as a separate .RData file in the working directory.

```
iter <- 1
save(iter, file="iter.RData")
```

Create a script which calls itself for the required number of iterations. Save the following script as "test_script.R"

```
###load iteration
library(rstudioapi)

load("iter.Rdata")

###insert function here.
time_now <- Sys.time()

###save output of function to a file.
save(time_now, file=paste0("time_", iter, ".Rdata"))

###update iteration
iter <- iter+1
save(iter, "iter.Rdata")

###restart session calling the script again
if(iter < 5){
restartSession(command='source("test_script.R")')
}
```

Enjoy!